# simple redirect using PHP - won't redirect

Tags: php, redirect, authentication

Please help me if you can, id appreciate it.

I have two files - index.php and home.php, The code at current sort of works, if I change the redirect to something like echo 'login successful' it works, but when i place the redirect code back it does not.

Index.php

```
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css"/>
<html>
<head>
    <title>SG - 2014</title>
</head>
<body background="images/strainsbackground.jpg">
<div id="allcolour">
<body>
<h1></h1>
<?php
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])){
?>
<a href="/register.php" style="text-decoration:none">
      <button  label="Register" name="so_link">Register</button>
</a>
<div id ="formcolour">
<!-- The HTML login form -->
    <form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
        Username: <br><input type="text" name="username" /><br />
        Password: <br><input type="password" name="password" /><br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />

        <a href="register.php">Register</a>
    </form>
    </div>

<?php
} else {
    require_once("db_const.php");
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    # check connection
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "<p>MySQL error no {$mysqli->connect_errno} : {$mysqli->connect_error}</p>";
        exit();
    }

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $sql = "SELECT * from users WHERE username LIKE '{$username}' AND password LIKE '{$password}' LIMIT 1";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    if (!$result->num_rows == 1) {
         echo "Invalid username/password combination";
    } else {
    $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['username'];
        header('location:home.php');
    }}


?>  

</body>
</div>
</div>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: PHP header must be above all the HTML. If not you will get `headers already sent` error.

Comment: 1. You should do exact username and password matching, otherwise there is a chance that it will select wrong user.
2. You should encrypt your passwords.

Not exactly what you asked, but you should consider that.

Comment: Encryption and other stuff will be implemented once my login actually works, thanks for the response

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set header after they had already sent.

Your code:

```
Output some html
Trying to set header LOCATION
More HTML
```

By sending HTML you send header and you can't manager headers after they had sent. Thats why your code doesn't work.

Do this:

```
Set header LOCATION
Output some html
```

So your code will be:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    require_once("db_const.php");
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    # check connection
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "<p>MySQL error no {$mysqli->connect_errno} : {$mysqli->connect_error}</p>";
        exit();
    }

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $sql = "SELECT * from users WHERE username LIKE '{$username}' AND password LIKE '{$password}' LIMIT 1";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    if (!$result->num_rows == 1) {
         echo "Invalid username/password combination";
    } else {
    $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['username'];
        header('location:home.php');
    }}


?>  

      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css"/>
<html>
<head>
    <title>SG - 2014</title>
</head>
<body background="images/strainsbackground.jpg">
<div id="allcolour">
<body>
<h1></h1>
<?php
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])){
?>
<a href="/register.php" style="text-decoration:none">
      <button  label="Register" name="so_link">Register</button>
</a>
<div id ="formcolour">
<!-- The HTML login form -->
    <form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
        Username: <br><input type="text" name="username" /><br />
        Password: <br><input type="password" name="password" /><br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />

        <a href="register.php">Register</a>
    </form>
    </div>

<?php
}
?>  

</body>
</div>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you for the response Sharikov! i have implemented your code but unfortunately still it does not work.

is this the correct code to go above the home.php file -

    <?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
    {
    header('location:index.php');
    }
    ?>

Comment: I don't know what means "it does not work". What output do you have? Are you sure you passing condition?

Comment: when i enter my credentials the page just refreshes and goes blank with the background image only displaying.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
header('location:home.php');
```

Use:

```
echo <<<EOT

<script>
document.location = 'home.php';
</script>

EOT;
```

Yes, too late for PHP, so use Javascript to redirect.

OR, move your PHP script to the top of the file. (UPDATED to include "session_start()".)

index.php:

```
<?php

session_start();

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    require_once("db_const.php");
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    # check connection
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "<p>MySQL error no {$mysqli->connect_errno} : {$mysqli->connect_error}</p>";
        exit();
    }

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $sql = "SELECT * from users WHERE username LIKE '{$username}' AND password LIKE '{$password}' LIMIT 1";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    if (!$result->num_rows == 1) {
        $error_msg = 'Invalid username/password combination';
    } else {
        $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['username'];
        header('location:home.php');
    }
}
?>  
<html>
<head>
    <title>SG - 2014</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css"/>
</head>
<body background="images/strainsbackground.jpg">
<div id="allcolour">
<body>

<?=$error_msg?>

<h1></h1>
<a href="/register.php" style="text-decoration:none">
      <button  label="Register" name="so_link">Register</button>
</a>
<div id ="formcolour">
<!-- The HTML login form -->
    <form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
        Username: <br><input type="text" name="username" /><br />
        Password: <br><input type="password" name="password" /><br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />

        <a href="register.php">Register</a>
    </form>
    </div>    
</body>
</div>
</div>
</html>
```

home.php:

```
<?php

session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    header('location:index.php');
}

// home

?>
```

Comment: Still with your code it is not working, can you tell me what code should be at the top of the home.php page please?

Comment: Maybe you didn't include session_start() in your php files.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't read all the code, but I think the problem is this line:

```
if (!$result->num_rows == 1) {
```

Try to change it into this one:

```
if ($result->num_rows !== 1) {
```